# How to iterate through a JSON file in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: python, json, post, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

### **Scene:**

I am using Azure DevOps pipelines as a security separator, so that my front end is not directly accessing my AKS.

**(Above is a business requirement I am not able to avoid or change in any way)**

### **What I got so far:**

I am able to put together a html post body with the information that I will be getting from my front end, and I am able to understand it and parse it out as JSON inside the Azure DevOps Pipeline. (using Python)

### **Issue:**

I <strike>need to</strike> must be able to iterate through each of the object in my JSON and execute actions as indicated.

### **JSON example:**

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "action(0)",
      "config": {
        "actionType": "Start"
        "stage": "test",
        "region": "North",
        "version": "v756"
        "customer": "Hans"
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "action(1)",
      "config": {
        "actionType": "Stop"
        "stage": "test",
        "region": "East",
        "version": "v752"
        "customer": "Christian"
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "action(2)",
      "config": {
        "actionType": "Delete"
        "stage": "prod",
        "region": "South",
        "version": "v759"
        "customer": "Anderson"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

** Edited (malformed JSON example)

### **TypeScript that generates my testing data**

```
const value = {
  actionType: "Create",
  stage: "test",
  region: "North",
  version: "v753",
  customer: "Hans"
}

interface Action {
    readonly action: string;
    readonly config: typeof value;
}

const actions: Array<Action> = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) actions.push({
    action: `action(${i})`,
    config: value
})

const result = JSON.stringify({ actions });

const body = {
    templateParameters: {
        actions: {
            value: result
        }
    }
}
```

** Edited: Added the TypeScript

### **Current pipeline**

```
name: Test-Deploy-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)-$(Date:hh-mm)$(Rev:.r)

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: actions
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
  - stage: test_stage
    displayName: Test stage
    jobs:
      - job: test
        displayName: Test the values
        steps:
        - ${{ each action in parameters.actions}}:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: Print out the "Action"-variable
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: '"${{action}}"'
```

** Edited: Added the pipeline as it stands

### **My current thinking:**

I would like to be able to iterate through the actions in a "for-each" fashion. Like in this pseudo pipeline script below:

```
- ${{ each action in $(actions) }}:
```

But I am not able to come up with exactly how that would be done in Azure DevOps Pipelines, so I am hoping that someone here can figure it out with me :)

Answer (score 0):

`${{ each }}` is a *template* expression. They're intended for use with parameters rather than variables, because they are evaluated at compile time (so `$(variablename)` can't have a value yet).

Now, I've not actually tried this myself, but the Runs API has a JSON request body element called `templateParameters`, which takes an object. What you could try is something like this:

1. Add a parameter to your pipeline, like:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: actions
  type: object
  default: []
```

2. When submitting the Runs API call to run your pipeline, include something like:

```json
{ 
  "previewRun": true,
  "templateParameters": {
    "actions": {
       ... your JSON actions content as generated in your question ... 
    },
  ... other parameters to your JSON run request
}
```

3. In your pipeline, reference

```yaml
- ${{ each action in parameters.actions }}:
```

The `previewRun` parameter will cause Azure Pipelines to not run the pipeline, but to return the compiled template for debugging and validation purposes. Remove it when you're ready to execute it.

Also, you'll likely need to do some experimenting with `templateParameters` to get something acceptable to the pipeline, like
declaring it as an array `"templateParameters": [ { "actions": [ your actions ] } ]` (as I said, I haven't actually done this, but the documentation suggests this might be a good path to explore).

Comment: I was just poking about, and I ran across this templateParameters as well... :) I will test this tomorrow, as my working day is over and I don't do work outside of work :)

Comment: Thanks so far @WaitingForGuacamole , but it is not quite there yet
So I am not currently able to get it working... (I added the TypeScript I use for generating the testing data in the question for you to look at)
When I used the `- ${{ each action in parameters.actions}}:` in the pipeline (Added the parameters declaration on top), my pipeline succeeds, because it never goes into that for each loop... I am guessing it is not finding the data in the array, so I most be doing something wrong

Comment: Added the TypeScript and the pipeline, so you can see what I am currently thinking...

Comment: In the Typescript that generates your data, try making "actions" an array as opposed to an object?

Comment: I do that:
 -> Make value
 -> Make Action object with action string and config that is of value type
 -> Make array called actions
 -> Fill it a number of times with stuff from the Action object
 -> Stringify it all - JSON Styles
 -> Make a body with tasks in it
 -> POST it into Azure DevOps Pipelines
 -> ?
 -> Profit!

Comment: Looking at your sample Typescript, it looks as though "actions" is an object `{}` rather than an array `[]`?

Comment: Took a bit, but I see what you are saying... it's an array in the TypeScript, but when I stuff it in my html post body I stuff them in as objects and not as arrays... got it :)

I will try how that changes things :)

Comment: @AndersOlesen Can you update the solution please?